# What are the punishments for the seven deadly sins?

Tags: christianity

In the first season of the TV show Slasher the antagonist is killing people he judges are guilty of the seven deadly sins. Each murder is different, supposedly reflecting the specific punishment the sinner would receive in hell for their sin.

I don't know how accurate the show's portrayals are, or even if they follow Christian tradition. What are the punishments for the seven deadly sins?

Comment: They are somewhat correct. Austins death in the show is by rat poison. His sin is gluttony, and The Executioner (antagonist) thought that it was close enough to use rat poison instead of rats. So, it isn't completely accurate, but it's very close, and represents a more modern version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since Medieval times the following punishments have been assigned to the 7 deadly sins.

1. **Pride** - You will be broken on the wheel
2. **Envy** - Placed in freezing water
3. **Gluttony** - Force fed rats, toads and snakes
4. **Lust** - Covered in fire and brimstone
5. **Wrath** - Live dismemberment
6. **Greed** - Boiled in oil
7. **Sloth** - Thrown into a snake pit

The list of the 7 sins came first from *Pope Gregory I* in *590 AD*.

Dante then wrote his *Purgatorio* & *Inferno* with descriptions given as to the punishments given for the sins. These were sometimes conflicted between the two books, for example in *Purgatorio* the punishment for lust was to be walk in flames, however in *Inferno* the souls of those that had committed the sin of lust were blown upon the winds.

Dante also wrote that anyone that committed any of the deadly sins would never be able to look upon the face of God.

Various Theologians came up with the accepted punishments detailed above over the centuries following Pope Gregory I's official naming of the sins.
Numerous books on the 7 Deadly sins, as well as a number of websites, for example [Sins, Virtues, and Tales](http://www.deadlysins.com/) explains these nicely.